# How to use a stack structure defined in a .h file?

Tags: struct, stack, typedef, pic, extern

I'm using mikroC for PIC IDE, I writing a firmware for PIC18F4550. I created a stack structure in a .h file and tried to use it in another file, a .c file. But, it did not work. 
In the .h file I did:

```
    struct Sstack {
      PTmenu stack[10];
      int top;
    };
    typedef struct Sstack Tstack;
```

The line :

```
    PTmenu stack[10];
```

is a array of pointers to another type, menu.

So, in the main function of the .c file, I did:

```
    Tstack stackMenu;
```

When I tried to compile I have this error :

```
    Undeclared identifier 'Tstack' in expression principal.c
```

I tried to use in the .c file :

```
    Tstack *stackMenu;
    stackMenu = (Tstack*)malloc(sizeof Tstack );
```

But, I had the same error as before:

```
    Undeclared identifier 'Tstack' in expression principal.c
```

I included the .h file in the .c file, but nothing helps. With what I explained here, can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: Sounds like the .h is not included. You say it is. Does the ,h have "the dance of the if defs" at the start to ensure it is only included once? If so are you sure you got that right?

Comment: @John3136, in the. h file there are others structs like this, and this error didn't appear. I will do the "dance of if defs" to see if it works. But, I'm really suspecting of the compiler of this mikro c for pic.

Comment: Where did you typedef PTmenu?